# How to make a table for loops?

Tags: programming, procedural-programming, infinite-loop

I have a code given by

```
V =((1/2 - (3 r)/2 + r^2) (r^8 (-1 + (3 r)/2) + 
4 (2 - (9 r)/2 + 2 r^2) + 2 r^4 (3 - 9 r + 6 r^2)))/(r^6 (2 + 
r^4)^2);

X= r + 5/2 ArcTan[4 (-(3/4) + r)] + 3/4 Log[1/2 - (3 r)/2 + r^2];

zz = X /. r -> 3/2

fV[z0_?NumericQ] :=With[{z = SetPrecision[z0 + zz, 100 + 1]},If[Abs[z] 
<= 35,Re[V /. FindRoot[X == z, {r, 10000001/10000000}, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 100]], 0]]
```

My problem: consider this formula*

```
Subscript[\[Psi], m, n, p] = 
Subscript[\[Psi], m - 1, n - 1, p] + Subscript[\[Psi], m, n, p - 1] -
Subscript[\[Psi], m - 1, n - 1, p - 1] - 
h^2/8 (fV[(p - (n - 1))/2 h] Subscript[\[Psi], m - 1, n - 1, p] + 
 fV[((p - 1) - n)/2 h] Subscript[\[Psi], m, n, p - 1])
```

with the following initial conditions

```
Subscript[\[Psi], 0, 0, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 1, 1, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 2, 2, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 3, 3, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 4, 4, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 5, 5, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 6, 6, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 7, 7, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 8, 8, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 9, 9, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 10, 10, 0] = 1;
Subscript[\[Psi], 0, 0, p] = Exp[-0.25 (p h)^2];
h = .5;
```

I need a table given by

```
Table[{t, Subscript[\[Psi], t/h, t/h, t/h]}, {t, 0, 5, h}]
```

as the result of calculations. How can I tell the Mathematica to calculate `Subscript[\[Psi], m, n, p]` from formula* and provide me the mentioned table? I will be thankful if someone helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a function instead of using `Subscript` (this is in general a good idea) and employ memoization (in order to preventing that values have to be computed multiple times:

```
ClearAll[fV];
fV[z0_?NumericQ] := fV[z0] = With[{z = SetPrecision[z0 + zz, 100 + 1]}, 
   If[Abs[z] <= 35, 
    Re[V /. FindRoot[X == z, {r, 10000001/10000000}, 
       MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 100]], 0]];

h = 1/2;
ClearAll[Ψ];
Ψ[0, 0, 0] = 1;
Ψ[1, 1, 0] = 1;
Ψ[2, 2, 0] = 1;
Ψ[3, 3, 0] = 1;
Ψ[4, 4, 0] = 1;
Ψ[5, 5, 0] = 1;
Ψ[6, 6, 0] = 1;
Ψ[7, 7, 0] = 1;
Ψ[8, 8, 0] = 1;
Ψ[9, 9, 0] = 1;
Ψ[10, 10, 0] = 1;
Ψ[0, 0, p_] := Ψ[0, 0, p] = Exp[- 1/4 (p h)^2];
Ψ[m_, n_, p_] := Ψ[m, n, p] = Ψ[m - 1, n - 1, p] + Ψ[m, n,  - 1] - Ψ[m - 1, n - 1, p - 1] - h^2/8 (fV[(p - (n - 1))/2 h] Ψ[m - 1, n - 1, p] + fV[((p - 1) - n)/2 h] Ψ[m, n, p - 1])
Table[{t, Ψ[t/h, t/h, t/h]}, {t, 0, 5, h}]
```

> {{0, 1}, {1/2, 0.936178}, {1, 0.766748}, {3/2, 0.54557}, {2, 0.330802}, {5/2, 0.161054}, {3, 0.0478391}, {7/2, -0.0171044}, {4, -0.0494697}, {9/2, -0.0633942}, {5, -0.068163}}

Comment: Thank you very much. When I employ it for higher values of `t`, say `t=21`, with `h=1/10` and `\[CapitalPsi][m_, n_, 0] := \[CapitalPsi][m, n, 0] = 1;`, I cannot make its table and it gives some FindRoot errors. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Consider `h=1/50`

Comment: I obtain plenty of recursion limit errors. Probably your initial conditions are not sufficient; the recursive evaluation of `Ψ` does not end up in one of the cases `Ψ[0, 0, 0]`, `Ψ[1, 1, 0]`,...., or `Ψ[0, 0, p]`. To `Ψ` calls itseld recursively over and over again infinitely often. Of course, a computer cannot do that so _Mathematica_ breaks this vicious circle at some point and throws an error.